# Is there a way to install the Ubuntu Software center offline?

Tags: 16.04, software-center, offline

I am using 16.04 lts, and after it wasn't working I deleted it on accident and now I do not have the Software Center nor any of my apps, (Inkscape, Blender, misc games.) My steam is running and programs that I downloaded before work.

Comment: Have you tried any of the options [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)?

Answer (score 0):

Its not necessary for your computer to have internet connection. However access to internet (on any device) is obviously required to get the installation files.

If you could arrange **.deb** file of the Software Centre by asking your friend run this to install.

`sudo dpkg -i /path-to-file/filename.deb`